# When adding a row in HTML table, the ID is NULL and not auto incremented

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server

I have an HTML table with 7 columns that has an insert button. Whenever the insert button is pressed, a dialog box appears and you can enter information. Upon adding the row, I want it to automatically assign the MR_ID column to whatever the MAX MR_ID is, +1. So for example if the max MR_ID is 300 and I add a row, I want that MR_ID of the added row to be 301, so basically like an auto increment. Currently, whenever I add a row the MR_ID shows as 0 in the table and is NULL in the database. MR_ID is a lookup for other tables so I can not have it set as NULL or the same number as another row. How can I do this?

I know this is a lot of code but if you have any questions, I will be here to help make my code any clearer for you if it can be.

HTML/PHP for Table:

```
<?php
    /* Foreach loop that brings in information to populate table */
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>">
        <td class="mr_id" id="<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" id="mr_name-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" name="field" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" id="buy_id<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" id="poc_n-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" id="poc_e-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" id="poc_p-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
// ----- Validation for each input in add row dialog box -----
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( mr_name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid vendor name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( buyer_id, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter a valid Buyer ID" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_n, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/, "Please enter a valid name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_e, emailRegex, "Please enter a valid email" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_p, phoneRegex, "Please enter a valid phone number" );
      console.log(allFields);
      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        var dict = {};
        var errors = "";
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val()+"-"+buyer_id );
          var type = $(this).attr('id');
          var value = $(this).val();
          console.log(type + " : " + value);
          // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
          switch (type) {
             case "mr_id":
                dict["MR_ID"] = value;
              break;
            case "mr_name":
                dict["MR_Name"] = value;
              break;
            case "buyer_id":
                dict["Buyer_ID"] = value;
              break;
            case "poc_n":
                dict["MR_POC_N"] = value;
              break;
            case "poc_e":
                dict["MR_POC_E"] = value;
                break;
            case "poc_p":
                dict["MR_POC_P"] = value;
                break;
            }
        });
        console.log(dict);
        $tr.find('.mr_id').html( $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).length + 1 );
        $( "#html_master tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );


        var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insert-copy.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row inserted");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to insert");
            console.log(response);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });


      }
      return valid;
    }
```

Ajax insert script:

```
<?php

  $MR_ID = $_POST['MR_ID'];
  $MR_Name = $_POST['MR_Name'];
  $Buyer_ID = $_POST['Buyer_ID'];
  $MR_POC_N = $_POST['MR_POC_N'];
  $MR_POC_E = $_POST['MR_POC_E'];
  $MR_POC_P = $_POST['MR_POC_P'];

  $host="xxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Master (MR_ID, MR_Name, Buyer_ID, MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E, MR_POC_P) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result = $stmt->execute(array($MR_ID, $MR_Name, $Buyer_ID, $MR_POC_N, $MR_POC_E, $MR_POC_P));
  echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: SQL Server calls their `auto_increment` columns an `identity` column. `auto_increment` is a MYSQL feature and isn't something that is standard across other databases, even though most other databases do have some sort of similar feature. You would need to setup that column as an `identity` column in management studio (or some other tool or alter statement).

Comment: Yes, thank you. I mixed up my terminology. I dont think I am able to use MR_ID as an identity column. There has been another column created in the table called "ID" and it is an identity column however. Although it is not used in my code currently.